# How can Delegate call many methods?

Tags: c#, delegates

Delegate is a reference to a method: 1 address to 1 memory cell, i.e. of our method. So when I link more methods to one delegate, how can this one address call many methods?

Comment: Do you want to understand the nature of multicast-delegates, which is a pretty broad question, or do you have any **specific** issue on them?

Answer (score 1):

> Delegate is a reference to a method: 1 address to 1 memory cell

Not necessarily it isn't. Delegates can be combined, via `+`, which is shorthand for `Delegate.Combine`. Invoking the composite delegate will involve each target in turn.

So:

```cs
SomeDelegate x = obj.Whatever;
SomeDelegate y = arg => other.SomeMethod(arg, capturedLocal);
SomeDelegate z = x + y;
z(42);
```

Comment: my question was about this case:                                                           
SomeDelegate x = obj.Whatever;
x += other.SomeMethod(arg, capturedLocal);
x+= another.Method();